# How to measure time of a cell and write the output to a file in Jupyter?

Tags: time, jupyter, capture

I'd like to measure time of a cell and write the output of the same cell to a file in Jupiter. I tried the following:

```
%%time
%%capture cap
-- My code --
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(cap.stdout)
```

However, I got NameError: name 'cap' is not defined. I think each function requires to be at the top of the cell. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running those in different cells?

First cell:

```
%%time
%%capture cap
-- your code that generates standard out while it runs --
```

Second cell below that one:

```py
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(cap.stdout)
```

You'll see the time reported when the first cell runs. And you can send the output to a file in the second one. I was worried in the same cell you couldn't use `cap.stdout` yet; however, I just tested **and what you wrote should be working**. Have you tried testing something simpler in a new notebook. Maybe you simply have a typo? I use `ls -lah` or `!ls -lah` for substituting the `--My code--` part for testing.

Comment: Thank you Wayne! I was also trying to save time in the output file, so I just put the "%%capture cap" first and then "%%capture cap". Then I run the second cell and both the output and time were saved.